# Converting varchar to decimal removes digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I made a SQL Server function that converts varchar to a decimal but it's removing digits and then returning a whole number.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ToMoney]
(
@Amount nvarchar
)
RETURNS decimal(14,2)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @finalAmount as decimal(14,2);          

IF Isnumeric(isnull(@amount, 0)) = 1
    SET @finalAmount = CAST(@amount as decimal(14,2))
ELSE
    SET @finalAmount = 0

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @finalAmount;
END
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT dbo.ToMoney('123.45') as result
```

The result is '1.00'

I want it to return 123.45 as a decimal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your function definition.  The use of `nvarchar()` with no length generally defaults in a length of `1`.

Try this:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ToMoney]
(
@Amount nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS decimal(14,2)
```

As a note:  when it defaults to the length of 1, it is taking the first character in the string.  That is why you are getting a value of `1.00`.